# how to write inline linq query from sql query

Tags: asp.net, linq

the below query is written in sql to select the recent activity of an salesperson based on last activity date

```
select UDV.User_dailyActivityId,UDV.userId,UDV.[DATE] ActivityDate,UDV.Activity,UDV.Subject 
      From [SalesTrack].[dbo].[UserDailyActivity]  UDV,
      (
        Select  userId,Max([DATE]) ActivityDate from [SalesTrack].[dbo].[UserDailyActivity]
        Group by userId
       ) GPUDV

      where udv.userId = GPUDV.userId and UDV.[DATE] = gpudv.ActivityDate
      order by udv.userId,UDV.[DATE]
```

i have to change the above query into linq, i am newbie in linq

i succeed writing the inline query part

```
var lastgroup=(from ua in db.UserDailyActivities group ua by ua.userId into GPua select new{GPua,ActivityDate=GPua.Max(ua=>ua.date)});
```

Please help me to finish the whole query

Comment: how to help..?????? Let us know what you want to achieve

Comment: What have you attempted to do? Have you tried to write it yourself? Simply asking for something isn't the right way to go.

Comment: i have edited my question please see the updated question and guide me

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
var result=
    (
        from UDV in db.UserDailyActivity
        from GPUDV in
        (
            from inner in db.UserDailyActivity
            group inner by inner.userId into g
            select new
            {
                userId=g.Key,
                ActivityDate=g.Max (x =>x.DATE)
            }
        ).Where (w =>w.userId==UDV.userId && w.ActivityDate==UDV.DATE)
        select new
        {
            UDV.User_dailyActivityId,
            UDV.userId,
            ActivityDate = UDV.[DATE],
            UDV.Activity,
            UDV.Subject
        }
    ).ToList();
```

where `db` is the linq data context